# Issue with OnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-application

I got an issue with SetOnClickListener in mine mobile kotlin app on AndroidStudio.
I created menu with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZWMPYIkNd8

Its ok! works fine on HAXM emulator but i can't manage to make mine button interactive..Tutorial guide tells me to initialize Button with SetOnClickListener

Android studio keeps asking me for more arguments and editors displays `not-enough-information-to-infer-parameter-t-with-kotlin-and-android` which makes me stuck.

I'm learning this language but resolving this problem is kinda out of mine range...what i need to know to properly implement OnClickListener?

Guy on youtube video doesnt put any extra phrase in brackets. so what i should do?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so we can help

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, but there are some problems in the current format/content of your question that makes it hard for some of us to help. If you haven't done so already, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it will be easier for us to help you. This may also be helpful: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: We are here to help , just post your code so we can help you and show you where the mistake is ec.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use braces {} instead of brackets after "view.setOnClickListener"

Answer (score 0):

You can implement OnClickListeners a few different ways.

For a simple implementation you can do the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        // do something when the user clicks the button
    }
}
```

Or you can have your activity handle it like so:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       <yourButton>.setOnClickListener(this)
    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
      when (v) {
        (<yourButton>) -> {

           // do something when the user clicks the button
        }
        else -> return
      }
    }

}
```

Here is a decent source if you want to read more. 
https://antonioleiva.com/lambdas-kotlin-android/